# В письме, отправленном через PHP mail некоторые буквы в словах заменяются на �

Tags: php, email

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Например, есть такой код:

```
<?
$text = 'PHP – это широко используемый язык сценариев общего назначения с открытым исходным кодом.
Говоря проще, PHP это язык программирования, специально разработанный для написания web-приложений (сценариев), исполняющихся на Web-сервере. Аббревиатура PHP означает "Hypertext Preprocessor (Препроцессор Гипертекста)". Синтаксис языка берет начало из C, Java и Perl. PHP достаточно прост для изучения. Преимуществом PHP является предоставление web-разработчикам возможности быстрого создания динамически генерируемых web-страниц. Подробнее о преимуществах PHP можно узнать здесь.
Важным преимуществом языка PHP перед такими языками, как языков Perl и C заключается в возможности создания HTML документов с внедренными командами PHP. Подробнее об этой возможность смотрите здесь. Значительным отличием PHP от какого-либо кода, выполняющегося на стороне клиента, например, JavaScript, является то, что PHP-скрипты выполняются на стороне сервера. Вы даже можете сконфигурировать свой сервер таким образом, чтобы HTML-файлы обрабатывались процессором PHP, так что клиенты даже не смогут узнать, получают ли они обычный HTML-файл или результат выполнения скрипта. PHP позволяет создавать качественные Web-приложения за очень короткие сроки, получая продукты, легко модифицируемые и поддерживаемые в будущем. PHP прост для освоения, и вместе с тем способен удовлетворить запросы профессиональных программистов. Даже если Вы впервые услышали о PHP, изучить этот язык не составит для Вас большого труда. Мы не сомневаемся, что изучив основы PHP в течение нескольких часов, вы уже сможете создавать простые PHP-скрипты. Язык PHP постоянно совершенствуется, и ему наверняка обеспечено долгое доминирование в области языков web-программирования, по крайней мере, в ближайшее время.';
$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
mail("my_mail@example.com", "Test", $text, $headers);
echo( $text);
```

Проблема в том, что в полученном письме в некоторых словах буквы заменяются на � (знак вопроса в ромбе). Если менять отправляемый текст, то проблема сохраняется.
Вот пример полученного текста:

> PHP – это широко используемый язык сценариев общего назначения с
> открытым исходным кодом. Говоря проще, PHP это язык программирования,
> специально разработанный для написания web-приложений (сценариев),
> исполняющихся на Web-сервере. Аббревиатура PHP означает "Hypertext
> Preprocessor (Препроцессор Гипертекста)". Синтаксис языка берет начало
> из C, Java и Perl. PHP достаточно прост для изучения. Преимуществом
> PHP является предоставление web-разработчикам возможности быстрого
> создания динамически генерируемых web-страниц. Подробнее о
> преимуществах PHP можно узнать здесь. Важным преимуществом языка PHP
> перед такими языками, как языков Perl и C заключается в возможности
> создания HTML документов с внедренными командами PHP. Подробнее об
> этой возможность смотрите здесь. Значительным отличием PHP от
> какого-либо кода, выполняющегося на стороне клиента, например,
> JavaScript, является то, что PHP-скрипты выполняются на стороне
> сервера. Вы даже можете сконфигурировать свой сервер таким образом,
> чтобы HTML-файлы обрабатывались процессором PHP, так что клиенты даже
> не смогут узнать, получают ли они обычный HTML-файл или результат вы�
> �олнения скрипта. PHP позволяет создавать качественные Web-приложения
> за очень короткие сроки, получая продукты, легко модифицируемые и
> поддерживаемые в будущем. PHP прост для освоения, и вместе с тем
> способен удовлетворить запросы профессиональных программистов. Даже
> если Вы впервые услышали о PHP, изучить этот язык не составит для Вас
> большого труда. Мы не сомневаемся, что изучив основы PHP в течение
> нескольких часов, вы уже сможете создавать простые PHP-скрипты. Язык
> PHP постоянно совершенствуется, и ему наверняка обеспечено долгое
> доминиро� �ание в области языков web-программирования, по крайней
> мере, в ближайшее время.

Дополнено:
Эта проблема проявляется на хостинге BlueHost. На другом хостинге Beget такой проблемы нет. Писал в службу поддержки BlueHost — решения не знают (

Comment: Вам нужно отправлять текст конкретно в кодировке utf8

Comment: А как именно это сделать? Там ведь указано в заголовке charset=utf-8

Comment: Кто-то где-то режет на чанки без учёта многобайтности кодировки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственный нормальный способ обойти это, который я вижу — преобразуйте тело в base64 с доп. заголовком: `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`

Согласно RFC 2045 стоит ещё самому на чанки(по 76 байт) порубить:

```
$body = chunk_split(base64_encode($body));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Помогло!